# How can I get a list of directories with ack?

Tags: macos, unix, ack

I have a directory listing as follows (given by `ls -la`):

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   6 <user>  <group>  204 Oct 18 12:13 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 <user>  <group>  238 Oct 18 11:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 <user>  <group>  476 Oct 18 12:31 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 <user>  <group>  601 Oct 18 12:03 index.html
drwxr-xr-x   2 <user>  <group>   68 Oct 18 12:13 test
drwxr-xr-x   2 <user>  <group>   68 Oct 18 12:13 test2
```

Running `ack . -f` prints out the files in the directory:

```
index.html
```

How can I get ack to print out the *directories* in the directory? I want to ignore the `.git` directory (which I understand is default behavior for ack). On that note, how can I ignore certain directories?

I am using ack 1.9.6 on Mac OSX 10.8.2.

Comment: Why do you want to use ack to list things instead of ls?

Comment: I need something I can readily pipe into `xargs`. My options are `find --print0` (weird syntax, trying to stay away from it) and `ack --print0`, both of which readily pipe into `xargs -0`.

Comment: So how is `ack --print0` less weird than `find -print0`? If you find a command hard to type/remember, make an alias.

Comment: `find . -name .git -a -type d -prune -o -type f -print0` simplifies to `ack . -f --print0`. Likewise, I want to find a way to simply `find . -name .git -a -type d -prune -o -type d -print0` into its ack equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  ack is only for files, not directories.  It is a text search tool, not a general purpose file finder.

To ignore directories, use the `--ignore-dir` option.